# Do I need to install driver for this graphics card on latest version of Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, intel-graphics

In 2009 Intel [released a driver](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19533/intel-graphics-media-accelerator-driver-for-windows-7-exe.html) for
my laptop with T4500 (2.3GHz) processor with Intel graphic media accelerator 4500M with shared graphic memory. I installed the latest version of window 7 (2020 update). Do I need to install that old driver on system or my windows itself contains better driver for this graphics card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the [Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=Graphics%20Media%20Accelerator) has a more recent version (9.14.3.1177 vs 8.15.10.1930). Bit confusing that they use 2 different version numbers.

Note that 2009 was the date of the first release, it has been updated since then.